# Fileset/patternset's refid attribute isn't expanded. How would you write a target that operates on an arbitrary set of files?

Tags: properties, nant, expansion, fileset

I have a set of targets that each do essentially the same thing except each contains a specific [patternset](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/types/patternset.html) on which to perform its tasks. I want to collapse these targets into a single "reusable" target that instead takes a set of files "as a parameter".

For example, this

```xml
<target name="echo1">
  <foreach item="File" property="fn">
    <in>
      <items>
        <include name="*.config"/>
      </items>
    </in>
    <do>
      <echo message="${fn}" />
    </do>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="echo2">
  <foreach item="File" property="fn">
    <in>
      <items>
        <include name="*.xml"/>
      </items>
    </in>
    <do>
      <echo message="${fn}" />
    </do>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="use">
  <call target="echo1"/>
  <call target="echo2"/>
</target>
```

would be replaced by

```xml
<patternset id="configs">
   <include name="*.config"/>
</patternset>

<patternset id="xmls">
   <include name="*.xml"/>
</patternset>

<target name="echo">
  <foreach item="File" property="fn">
    <in>
      <items>
        <patternset refid="${sourcefiles}"/>
      </items>
    </in>
    <do>
      <echo message="${fn}" />
    </do>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="use">
  <property name="sourcefiles" value="configs"/>
  <call target="echo"/>
  <property name="sourcefiles" value="xmls"/>
  <call target="echo"/>
</target>
```

However, it turns out that `refid` is not expanded as answered in a [nant-dev email posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-developers@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03904.html) because patternsets and filesets differ from properties. In this non-working code, when `echo` is called, its `patternset` element references a patternset literally named **${sourcefiles}** instead of the one named **test**.

How would one write a re-usable NAnt target that operates on a varying set of files?  Is there a way to do this in NAnt as-is without resorting to writing custom tasks?

Comment: The 2nd link doesn't point to the nant-dev email posting but to NAnt patternset documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally came up with this, which serves my purposes. As a bonus, this also demonstrates calling a target dynamically.

```xml
<project
  name="dynamic-fileset"
  default="use"
  xmlns="http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.86-beta1/nant.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <target name="configs">
        <fileset id="files">
           <include name="*.config"/>
        </fileset>
    </target>

    <target name="xmls">
        <fileset id="files">
           <include name="*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
    </target>

    <target name="echo">
      <foreach item="File" property="fn">
        <in>
          <items refid="files"/>
        </in>
        <do>
          <echo message="${fn}" />
        </do>
      </foreach>
    </target>

    <target name="use">
      <property name="grouplist" value="xmls,configs"/>
      <foreach item="String" in="${grouplist}" delim="," property="filegroup">
        <do>
          <call target="${filegroup}"/>
          <call target="echo"/>
        </do>
      </foreach>        
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - smart workaround! You saved me tons of time. I've messed around with refid's and filesets for several hours, till i found this. I really have to spit on Nant, it's an amazing demonstration of how to over-complicate things, when simple features, like dynamic refids on a fileset or multiple fileset support in foreach are left out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood what You're trying to achieve, but shouldn't attribute `dynamic` of [task `property`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/property.html) do the job?

```
<target name="filesettest">
  <property name="sourcefiles" value="test" dynamic="true" />
  <!-- ... -->
</target>
```

Comment: That was actually my second attempt, but that controls when the property gets its value. In NAnt code, reference types used for tasks aren't subject to property expansion so no luck there.